# Applescript or widget to create an overlay timer on a Keynote presentation

Tags: cocoa, applescript, powerpoint, keynote

Following the idea of this thread:
[Display Cocoa window above Keynote presentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6233702/display-cocoa-window-above-keynote-presentation)
(which I don't if the author found a solution),

I'd like to know if it's possible to add an overlay timer or logo on a keynote presentation in fullscreen mode, with an applescript or a widget.

Thanks

Comment: Does this really have anything to do with PowerPoint?  If so, please explain the connection.  If not, you might want to remove the "powerpoint" tag.

Comment: With a window based app you can create a floating, transparent window with any content you like. Pure applescript won't work. ASOC might work but I would recommend objective c. Basically that's what the other guy did. He just struggled with the windows level to appear on top of the presentation.